# ibatis Serach Queston when condition like Like '$propertyname$%'

Tags: ibatis, ibatis.net

when i use ibatis,I have a sql like that

```
select * from user where name like '%$name$%'
```

if i set the username value is ???, it throw a exception,System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException. 
i know i can do like that

```
mysql: select * from user where name like concat('%',#name #,'%')  

oracle: select * from user where name like '%'||#name #||'%'

SQL Server:select * from user where name like '%'+#name #+'%
```

to avoid this question.
but i don't know why i use like '%$name$%' it throw exception.